# How to Retrieve Data directly from the Firebase Cloud Firestore into a CUSTOM JAVA OBJECT

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I cant insert the image, you can visit the link above or read the description below.
This is how the Document in the Firestore is present -

```
Profile

DOB 23032001
age 19
membership "GOLD"
name "Saheel"
trainer_name "trainer1"
```

I added the data manually through the Firebase console. Now I want to retrieve the data into an Custom Java Object which i have created in the application.
This object is tailor made for the document.
Test class -

```java
package com.example.firebase;

public class test {
    private String name;
    private int DOB;
    private int age;
    private String membership;
    private String trainer_name;

    public test(String name, int DOB, int age, String membership, String trainer_name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.age = age;
        this.membership = membership;
        this.trainer_name = trainer_name;
    }

    public test(){
        //no-argument constructor
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(int DOB) {
        this.DOB = DOB;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getMembership() {
        return membership;
    }

    public void setMembership(String membership) {
        this.membership = membership;
    }

    public String getTrainer_name() {
        return trainer_name;
    }

    public void setTrainer_name(String trainer_name) {
        this.trainer_name = trainer_name;
    }
}
```

The code which requests the data from the database -

```
//CUSTOM OBJECTS

        db.collection("users").document("Saheel").collection("profile")
                .document("profile").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                test test =documentSnapshot.toObject(com.example.firebase.test.class);
                name_t.setText(test.getName());
                age_t.setText(test.getAge());
                dob_t.setText(test.getDOB());
                membership_t.setText(test.getMembership());
                trainer_t.setText(test.getTrainer_name());
            }
        });
```

The Application crashes immediately and the logcat shows the below error -

```
2020-10-07 20:50:30.366 9016-9016/com.example.firebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebase, PID: 9016
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x13
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
        at com.example.firebase.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:81)
        at com.example.firebase.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:76)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Am I following the right procedure? Is it possible to do this Operation in Firestore?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that's generating this error.  What you have here so far isn't enough.  The stack trace is pointing to a call to setText in your MainActivity.

Comment: @DougStevenson changes made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `text.getDOB()` returns an int, this code is trying to put an integer into a TextView:

```
dob_t.setText(test.getDOB());
```

When you call setText with an integer, Android takes that integer to be a string resource with the given numeric ID.  Since Android can't find that string resource, it crashes.

If you need to show a number as a string in a TextView, you will need to convert it to a string first:

```
dob_t.setText(Integer.toString(test.getDOB()));
```

Comment: ```at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)```
How did you figure this out from the above lines? what does those number codes refer to ?

Comment: I've been doing Android development for a long time. This is a common point of confusion.